# How can I determine the row index of a parking space?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This represents a parking lot with 7 rows, containing a total of 392 spaces:

[image: grid]

In the example above, the row indexes from left to right would be:

```
row[0] (spaces 392-337)
row[1] (spaces 336-381)
row[2] (spaces 280-225)
row[3] (spaces 224-169)
row[4] (spaces 268-113)
row[5] (spaces 112-57)
row[6] (spaces 56-1)
```

What is an equation that would return the row (r) for a given parking space (s)?

e.g.

```
r = EquationToFindRowForSpace(s)
r = EquationToFindRowForSpace(273)
r = 2
```

Comment: Have you tried using % (mod) and integer division?

Comment: @ncmathsadist Actually aren't they talking about columns, not rows, (mistake in the definition) thus it would just be $Row(r) = 6-floor(r/56)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one seventh of the spaces are in each row, you need to find which seventh the space lies in, and then, since you numbered the rows from left to right, reverse the order. Therefore $r(s)=6-\lfloor{\frac {7(r-1)}{392}}\rfloor=6-\lfloor{\frac {r-1}{56}}\rfloor$.

Edit: Sorry, just saw Dane Bouchie's comment. Same thing with floor symbols.